# Passing a JSON Extract from a rest api to a SQL Server in python

Tags: python, json, sql-server

I'm very new to py programming; please excuse if its a silly question.

I need to perform two actions

1. Extract json file from a Rest API (which will have a very large number of Key/Value pairs)
2. Pass the extract in a tabular format to a SQL Server

I have written a sample function consisting of only 03 parameters which are passed on to a SQL Server on my system.

How will this function change if there are unknown number of parameters as in the case of a json extract?

```
def InsertJsonsql(Name, City, Age):
    connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                'Server=IN2367403W1\SQLEXPRESS;' #IN2367403W1\SQLEXPRESS : use server name 
                                'Database=TestDB;'
                                'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = connection.cursor()

json_insert_query = """
                        INSERT INTO TestDB.dbo.Person (Name, City, Age) VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}') 
                    """.format(Name, City, Age)


cursor.execute(json_insert_query)
connection.commit()
print("Record inserted successfully into Person table")
```

Comment: You seem using relational database. In such database, size of parameters are fixed when tables are made. If you want to input unknow nums of JSON, you might use NoSQL.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned from [@shimo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59797158/passing-a-json-extract-from-a-rest-api-to-a-sql-server-in-python#comment105736353_59797158) in the comments a relational database like mysql or Windows SQL are fixed when created. So you can't add new columns to handle unknown number of parameters.

As far as I know you have 2 options:

1.) Use a NoSQL database like MongoDB. There the data is saved as JSON and therefore it can handle any number of key-value pairs. This is the safest and best method.

2.) If you have to use a relational database you may have to create a column in your table that can handle a long String and save your data as JSON String in this column. This is not a good solution and you should rather use a NoSQL database.